# Extract string between characters at the end of a URL

Tags: javascript

I have the following example url: `http://example.com/this/is/the/end/`

I need to extract the last piece of the url, between the last two `/`

There may be characters after the last `/` but it's always between the last two  `/` that I need.

This is what I'm trying, I think it's pretty close but it only returns the **d** of **end**

How can I extract the full **end**?

**Javascript**

```
var str = 'http://example.com/this/is/the/end/';

var string = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("/")-1,str.lastIndexOf("/"));
```

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/esz5pt7g/)

Comment: `var last = /\/(\w+)\/$/g.exec(str)[1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply split and slice

```
'http://example.com/this/is/the/end/'.split('/').slice(-2)[0]
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `lastIndexOf` with *start from index* as second parameter to extract the text between the two slashes.

```js
var str = 'http://example.com/this/is/the/end/';

var lastIndex = str.lastIndexOf('/');
var string = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("/", lastIndex - 1) + 1, lastIndex);
//                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ : Get the last `/` index by starting search from `lastIndex - 1` index.

console.log(string);
```

---

You can also use string and array functions as follow.

```js
var str = 'http://example.com/this/is/the/end/';

var string = str.split('/').slice(-2)[0];

console.log(string);
```

---

Also, regex can be used.

[**Regex Demo and Explanation**](https://regex101.com/r/cA4sD3/1)

```js
var str = 'http://example.com/this/is/the/end/';

var string = str.match(/\/(\w+)\/[^\/]*?$/)[1];

console.log(string);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a good place to use regular expressions:

[**Regex Live Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/cA4sD3/2)

```
var str = 'http://example.com/this/is/the/end/';
var re = /\/([^\/]*)\/[^\/]*$/;
//        \/  - look for /
//          ([^\/]*) - capture zero or more characters that aren't a /
//                  \/ - look for last /
//                    [^\/]* - look for more chars that aren't /
//                          $ - match the end of the string
var last = re.exec(str)[1];
console.log(last); //end
```